# Github actions branch filter. Could not use 'release/' prefix on push workflow trigger

Tags: github, github-actions

When I am pushing a branch with the name pattern "release/**" then for some reason Github action will not be executed:

```
name: Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'release/[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'
```

In case I change "release/" to "releases/" it works just great.
Does "release" word is somehow reserved by Github? I could not find an explanation for this in docs.

Comment: Did you push this workflow on the default branch, or it is only available on your feature branch? This might be the case because GitHub Actions would normally trigger with the workflow file from your default branch (e.g. main, master ) and if it is still containing the old version with releases/ branch, it would NOT work with release/ branch until you merge your code into the default branch.